# react input value needs to be set by useState hook in order to run onChange event but it's empty after I run a mutation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, aws-amplify

I am using aws amplify react and graphql

I am primarily concerned with the input inside of the `recipe.ingredients.items.map` It will show the correct value on refresh if I use val.ingredient as the value, but then I can't update the input via the `onChange`, the input just does nothing, which makes sense, but how to I get the new update value from the `updateCurrentIngredient` function to show on refresh. Do I need a subscription, but I'm not sure how that may even help me.

Ideally when I tab out or click out of the input I want to run `updateIngredient` mutation and when I refresh the page the input to reflect the change.

The reason I want to do this is, eventually I want to be able to add multiple ingredients, but before I can add a new ingredient input row I need to be able to update an ingredient.

So this is my edit page of a Recipe, that needs to be able to add ingredients with a repeater button, new row new ingredient, but I am first focusing on just being able to update one ingredient.

If you have any better ideas for architecting this I am all ears.

Thanks ahead of time

Here is my code thus far

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { API } from "aws-amplify";
import { updateIngredient, updateRecipe } from "./graphql/mutations";
import { getRecipe } from "./graphql/queries";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function EditRecipe() {
  const [recipe, setRecipe] = useState(null);
  const [ingredients, setIngredients] = useState(null);
  let { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchRecipe();
    async function fetchRecipe() {
      if (!id) return;
      const recipeData = await API.graphql({
        query: getRecipe,
        variables: { id },
        authMode: "API_KEY",
      });
      setRecipe(recipeData.data.getRecipe);
      setIngredients(recipeData.data.getRecipe.ingredients);
    }
  }, [id]);

  if (!recipe) return null;

  function onChange(e) {
    setRecipe({ ...recipe, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  const { name } = recipe;

  async function updateCurrentPost() {
    if (!name) return;
    await API.graphql({
      query: updateRecipe,
      variables: { input: { name, id } },
      authMode: "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
    });
    console.log("post successfully updated!");
  }

  if (!ingredients) return null;

  function onChangeIngredient(e) {
    setIngredients({ ...ingredients, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    console.log(e);
  }

  async function updateCurrentIngredient(id, ingredient) {
    console.log(id + " " + ingredients.ingredient);
    if (!ingredients) return;
    await API.graphql({
      query: updateIngredient,
      variables: { input: { ingredient: ingredients.ingredient, id } },
      authMode: "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
    });
    console.log("ingredient succesfully updated");
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {recipe && (
          <input
            name="name"
            value={recipe.name}
            placeholder="name"
            value={recipe.name}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        <>
          {recipe.ingredients.items.map((val, i) => {
            return (
              <ul key={i}>
                <li>
                  <p>Choose ingredient</p>
                  <input
                    name="ingredient"
                    placeholder="name"
                    value={ingredients.ingredient}
                    onChange={onChangeIngredient}
                    onBlur={() => {
                      updateCurrentIngredient(val.id);
                    }}
                  />
                </li>
              </ul>
            );
          })}
        </>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={updateCurrentPost}>Update Post</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default EditRecipe;
```

Update: I am still quite stuck on this, I ahve tried moving the inptu into it;s own component, what confuses me is how do I get the value from the map into the input, as well as updating it, In this code below that I have modified the input value does not work at all. Which does make sense, but I don't know what to do at this point.

```
// pages/edit-post/[id].js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { API } from "aws-amplify";
import { updateIngredient, updateRecipe } from "./graphql/mutations";
import { listIngredients } from "./graphql/queries";
import { getRecipe } from "./graphql/queries";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import Ingredient from "./Ingredient";

function IngredientInput(props) {
  const [ingredients, setIngredients] = useState(props.item);

  const onChangeIngredient = (e) => {
    setIngredients({ ...ingredients, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  async function updateCurrentIngredient(id, ingredient) {
    console.log(id + " " + ingredients.ingredient);
    if (!ingredients) return;
    await API.graphql({
      query: updateIngredient,
      variables: { input: { ingredient: ingredients.ingredient, id } },
      authMode: "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
    });
    console.log("ingredient succesfully updated");
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input value={props.item.ingredient} onChange={onChangeIngredient} />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          updateCurrentIngredient(props.item.id);
        }}
      >
        Save ingredient
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function EditRecipe() {
  const [recipe, setRecipe] = useState(null);
  const [ingredients, setIngredients] = useState(null);
  let { id } = useParams();

  //console.log(id);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchRecipe();
    async function fetchRecipe() {
      if (!id) return;
      const recipeData = await API.graphql({
        query: getRecipe,
        variables: { id },
        authMode: "API_KEY",
      });
      setRecipe(recipeData.data.getRecipe);
      setIngredients(recipeData.data.getRecipe.ingredients);
    }
  }, [id]);

  if (!recipe) return null;

  function onChange(e) {
    setRecipe({ ...recipe, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  const { name } = recipe;

  async function updateCurrentPost() {
    if (!name) return;
    await API.graphql({
      query: updateRecipe,
      variables: { input: { name, id } },
      authMode: "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
    });
    console.log("post successfully updated!");
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {recipe && (
          <input
            name="name"
            value={recipe.name}
            placeholder="name"
            value={recipe.name}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        {/* {recipe.ingredients.items && ( */}
        <>
          {ingredients.items.map((val, i) => {
            return (
              <IngredientInput key={i} item={val} />
            );
          })}
        </>
        {/* )} */}
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={updateCurrentPost}>Update Post</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default EditRecipe;
```

Comment: handler doesn't use input value ... make ingredient row a separate component (pass value and update handler)

Comment: @xadm not sure I quite follow you. Are you saying where I do the map function to make that entire block into it's own component. Or just the input into it;s own componenet? and what value am I passing. Could you explain more.

Comment: follow some react todo tutorial ? updating fn leave in recipe ... `<IngredientInput id={id} value={val} onChange={updateCurrentIngredient} />`  `onChangeHandler ... value=e.target.value; console.log(props.id, value); props.onChange( props.id, value);`

Answer (score 1):

Ok a couple issues here but let me see if I can answer.

Every time you update state using `setIngredients` the `useEffect` handler is fired, which then wipes out your recipe and ingredient list and makes you page rerender. You should move your call to `fetchRecipe` to where you currently have `console.log("post successfully updated!")`

**-- On an unrelated note --**

In React you should NEVER declare new methods as part of a render method. When you do, you cause every change to anything to rerender your whole component which is worse than death for performance and usability. Whatever logic you would put into such a method should be static or part of a sub-component. You should also not use index as a key in your mapping function, use an identifier like `ingredient.name` instead.

Comment: are you suggesting I take the fetchRecipe function outside the useEffect, otherwise how do I run fetchRecipe in the updateCurrentPost function as you suggest. I thought it needed to be in this useEffect, so it runs in first load and any change of the ID. For the unrelated note, which part of my code are you referring to for declaring new methods as part of a render method? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm suggesting. I see now why you wanted to invoke it inside useEffect, but it needs to be gated on the ID changing for that to work.
In this style of component, your whole method is equivalent to the render method on a react class. Your onClick listener declares a lambda which will make the component rerender too often.

Answer (score 0):

Although it may not be an ideal solution here is what I came up with based on the othe answer and comments

```
// pages/edit-post/[id].js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { API } from "aws-amplify";
import { updateIngredient, updateRecipe } from "./graphql/mutations";
import { listIngredients } from "./graphql/queries";
import { getRecipe } from "./graphql/queries";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import Ingredient from "./Ingredient";

function IngredientInput(props) {
  let { id } = useParams();

  const [ingredients, setIngredients] = useState(props.item);

  const onChangeIngredient = (e) => {
    setIngredients([{ ...ingredients, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }]);
  };

  async function fetchRecipe() {
    if (!id) return;
    const recipeData = await API.graphql({
      query: getRecipe,
      variables: { id },
      authMode: "API_KEY",
    });
    setIngredients(recipeData.data.getRecipe.ingredients.items);
    console.log(recipeData.data.getRecipe.ingredients.items);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchRecipe();
  }, [id]);

  async function updateCurrentIngredient(id, ingredient) {
    console.log(id + " " + ingredient);
    if (!ingredients) return;
    await API.graphql({
      query: updateIngredient,
      variables: { input: { ingredient: ingredient, id } },
      authMode: "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
    });
    console.log("ingredient succesfully updated");
  }

  console.log(ingredients);

  return (
    <div>
      {ingredients.map((test, i) => {
        return (
          <React.Fragment key={i}>
            <input
              name="ingredient"
              value={test.ingredient}
              onChange={onChangeIngredient}
            />
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                updateCurrentIngredient(props.id, test.ingredient);
              }}
            >
              Save ingredient
            </button>
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

function EditRecipe() {
  const [recipe, setRecipe] = useState(null);
  const [ingredients, setIngredients] = useState(null);
  let { id } = useParams();

  //console.log(id);

  async function fetchRecipe() {
    if (!id) return;
    const recipeData = await API.graphql({
      query: getRecipe,
      variables: { id },
      authMode: "API_KEY",
    });
    setRecipe(recipeData.data.getRecipe);
    setIngredients(recipeData.data.getRecipe.ingredients);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchRecipe();
  }, [id]);

  if (!recipe) return null;

  function onChange(e) {
    setRecipe({ ...recipe, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  const { name } = recipe;

  async function updateCurrentPost() {
    if (!name) return;
    await API.graphql({
      query: updateRecipe,
      variables: { input: { name, id } },
      authMode: "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
    });
    fetchRecipe();
    console.log("post successfully updated!");
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {recipe && (
          <input
            name="name"
            value={recipe.name}
            placeholder="name"
            value={recipe.name}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        {/* {recipe.ingredients.items && ( */}
        <>
          {ingredients &&
            ingredients.items.map((val, i) => {
              return (
                <IngredientInput id={val.id} key={i} item={ingredients.items} />
              );
            })}
        </>
        {/* )} */}
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={updateCurrentPost}>Update Post</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default EditRecipe;
```

Comment: `ingredients.items.map((val, i) => <IngredientInput`